# Javascript remove everything before special character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying remove everything before a string like

`234234$12$34`

Where everything is removed before the first found `$` ? And then split the `$12$34` to like `$12,$34` ?

How am I able to do that in regex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 parts = "234234$12$34".match(/\$[^$]+/g)
```

returns

```
 ["$12", "$34"]
```

Comment: wow awesome thanks heaps :) that's probably the fastest response i've ever received! so +1 to you